# Cutting nails before Yom Tov

Tags: halacha, shabbat, calendar, yom-tov, nail-cutting

BSD

I know that it says in Shulchan Aruch one shouldn't cut one's nails on Thursday (really two days before Shabbat) in deference to the Shabbos.

1. **Does this apply to Yom Tov as well?** Meaning, should one not cut
   their nails two days before a Yom Tov either?
2. **What happens when Yom Tov and Shabbos come into conflict?** If Yom Tov is Thursday night, may one cut their nails in honor of the Yom Tov even though it's Thursday?